# Why the end value is excluded in the range function in python?

Tags: python

In a range(start, end) function in python, why the end value is excluded

```py
print(0,6) # prints numbers from 0 to 5 and the end value 6 is exlcuded
```

I just want to know why the range function is designed in such a way. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: One reason is to match the indices in a list

Comment: You can also specify arguments from where to start. The one you said is the default behavior.

Comment: Also, range is not a function. It is an immutable sequence of numbers.

Comment: Because that is how it was designed.?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use an end value, you get that many numbers.

```
>>> range(6)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> len(range(6))
6
```

Comment: Could `range` have included the *`stop`* number and still produce indices that match?

Comment: Yes, I suppose. I've edited my answer.